# Как сформировать новую таблицу одним запросом?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Изучаю T-SQL, у меня есть задача: есть таблица из одного столбца:

```
2017-02-01 15:00:43
2017-03-18 10:30:10
2017-12-11 01:21:55
2017-12-11 15:33:03
2017-03-18 10:30:10
2017-02-22 08:40:42
2017-06-06 23:59:40
```

Мне нужно написать один запрос без процедурных компонентов, без хп, временных таблиц и оконных функций, который сделает из нее таблицу из двух столбцов таким образом, чтобы каждая дата была закрыта следующей датой:

```
2017-02-01 15:00:43 2017-02-22 08:40:42
2017-02-22 08:40:42 2017-03-18 10:30:10
2017-03-18 10:30:10 2017-03-18 10:30:10
2017-03-18 10:30:10 2017-06-06 23:59:40
2017-06-06 23:59:40 2017-12-11 01:21:55
2017-12-11 01:21:55 2017-12-11 15:33:03
2017-12-11 15:33:03 null
```

Помогите решить данную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.date, MIN(t2.date)
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t1.date < t2.date
GROUP BY t1.date
```